# Spring 5 REST testing WebTestClient null

Tags: rest, unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm trying to learn how to test REST in SpringBoot. I've rewritten code from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html and changed it a bit to suit my needs, but my `testClient` variable is null all the time. I've tried to instantiate in manually e.g. by using this:

```
WebTestClient testClient = WebTestClient
  .bindToServer()
  .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
  .build();
```

or by building it by using ApplicationContext:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

WebTestClient testClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context)
  .build();
```

Nothing works, but when I'm trying to use the ApplicationContext way, my stacktrace says "ApplicationContext is required".

This is how my code looks right now:

```
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class BusinessProcessControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient testClient;

    @Test
    public void returns_type_JSON(){
        testClient.get().uri("/businessProcess").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
```

In Spring tutorial, they didnt even use the `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient`, but it wouldn't work if I hadn't added it to the code. What else could be missing? In this version, I get NullPointerException all the time - the debugger says that `testClient` is null. How can I make it work so further test writing will be possible?

Comment: Have you tried adding  `spring-boot-starter-webflux` as a test dependency?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hard to call it solution but I've added an answer if you also need help with testing

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve this problem, but used another classes instead. I'm not very satisfied with this, but it works so this is what I've used in this class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
public class BusinessProcessControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

I use `MockMvc` object to perform HTTP methods like this:

```
@Test
    public void businessProcessSetImportanceReturns201ForExistingResource() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(postAsAdmin("/businessProcesses/2/setImportance")).andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }
```

Where "postAsAdmin" method is my own implementation, here's how it works under the hood:

```
public static MockHttpServletRequestBuilder postAsAdmin(String urlTemplate, Object... uriVars) {
        return MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(urlTemplate, uriVars).with(httpBasic(ADMIN_USERNAME, PASSWORD));
    }
```